# Repairing an iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, screen

I've got a broken screen on my iPhone 4.  Does anyone have any hints, suggestions, or products that you have used to repair your broken screen?  Is there anything different about the iPhone 4 vs other iOS devices (due to the Gorilla Glass)?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the [iFixIt kit](http://www.ifixit.com/iPhone-Parts/iPhone-4-Display-Assembly/IF182-003) and [guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-iPhone-4-Display-Assembly/3148/1). It's gonna be expensive since unlike of the  the previous versions iPhone, on iPhone4 you can't just change the glass without the changing LCD..

Comment: I would like to point out that that option is $150 with lots of of time, effort, and risk.  Going through Apple is $200 and is fast, easy, and warranty-able.

Comment: @Christian "fast" is only in USA and some countries.

Comment: I replaced the glass on my 3GS with a kit from them and there were two big problems. First, it was actually quite difficult to do; if you don't have a lot of electronics experience and, especially, are used to doing things like using a heat gun to release glue, etc., I don't recommend doing it yourself. Second, the oleophobic coating of the original Apple part is way, **way** nicer: my screen gets gross very quickly and requires near-constant cleaning, and it doesn't clean well without a ton of rubbing. Wish I'd taken it to Apple, even with the significantly greater price.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have your IPhone fixed or replaced by now, but maybe others will find this useful.

I faced the same problem last Sunday - IPhone 4 glass shattered in thousand places after being dropped on the floor. We used [iFixYourI](http://www.ifixyouri.com/34-iphone-4-repair) to replace the screen assembly - they have a location in Boston, and it only took 20 minutes + about $130. On iPhone4 only the entire glass + digitizer + LCD assembly can be replaced. I would suggest googling "iphone 4 screen replacement" to see your local outlets first; if nothing is available nearby iFixYourI or others will still accept your phone by mail; Finally, if you want to DIY  then screen assemblies can now be purchased now for less than $100.

Hope this helps.